# R: classifying a text variable

Tags: r, regex, string, performance

I have a data frame with a string variable representing diagnoses of diseases. I want to classify the diagnoses according to some rules:

```
rules <- list(
  group1 = c('A012', 'A02', 'C30'),
  group2 = c('B01', 'B02')
)
```

If the diagnosis field contains 'A01', 'A02' or 'A03' (including text that includes these patterns, e.g. 'A0199'), then the case should be put in group 1, and so on.

My data looks like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  ID = seq_len(10),
  diagnosis = c('A012', 'A01', 'B23', 'C43', 'B023', 'A99', 'A023', 'B012', 'B04', 'A07')
)
```

The method I've used looks like this:

```
# modify the rules so they work with grep    
rules <- lapply(rules, paste, collapse = '|')

# create a function that classifies an individual diagnosis
group <- function(y) {
      a <- sapply(rules, grepl, x = y)
      a <- names(a)[a]
      return(if (length(a) == 0) NA else a)
    }

# apply the function across the data frame
dat$group <- sapply(dat$diagnosis, group)
```

This seems to work, but my dataset is big and there are lots of rules, and it is extremely slow!

Are there faster ways I could do this?

Comment: Are the rules are always of 3 character length?, if so, you could potentially just shorten  `diagnosis` and do an exact match

Comment: No, the rules are of varying lengths unfortunately! I've modified the example to show this.

Comment: How many rules you have in total in your real data set?

Comment: There are 10 groups, each with different numbers of diagnoses, averaging 4 diagnoses per group (if that makes sense...)

Comment: So about 40? Can you try this on your real dataset and tell me if it fast? `library(stringi) ; rules_dt <- list(rules = unlist(rules, use.names = FALSE), grp = rep(seq_len(length(rules)), lengths(rules))) ; lapply(1:length(rules_dt[[1]]), function(x) dat[stri_detect_fixed(dat$diagnosis, rules_dt$rules[x]), "group"] <<- rules_dt$grp[x])`

Comment: Yes, thank you! It's fast - almost instant with my dataset. I just need to work out how it works now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of rules isn't too big (OP says it's only 40), we could just run over the rules and perform an exact match using `stringi::stri_detect_fixed` (which is much faster than using regex)

First, we will flatter `rules`

```
rules_dt <- list(rules = unlist(rules, use.names = FALSE), 
                 grp = rep(seq_len(length(rules)), lengths(rules)))
```

Then, define the function

```
library(stringi)
f <- function(x) dat[stri_detect_fixed(dat$diagnosis, rules_dt$rules[x]), "group"] <<- rules_dt$grp[x]
```

Then, run it per rule

```
invisible(lapply(seq_len(length(rules_dt[[1]])), f))
dat
#    ID diagnosis group
# 1   1      A012     1
# 2   2       A02     1
# 3   3       B23    NA
# 4   4       C43    NA
# 5   5      B023     2
# 6   6       A99    NA
# 7   7      A023     1
# 8   8      B012     2
# 9   9       B04    NA
# 10 10       A07    NA
```

---

**Benchmark**: On .5MM rows and 10 groups of 10 it runs for about ~4 secs on my laptop

```
library(stringi)
n <- 10
N <- 5e5

set.seed(123)
rules <- setNames(replicate(n, 
                  stri_rand_strings(n = n, length = 4), simplify = FALSE), 
                  paste0("group", 1:n))

dat <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:N,
  diagnosis = stri_rand_strings(N, 4),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

system.time({
  rules_dt <- list(rules = unlist(rules, use.names = FALSE), 
                   grp = rep(seq_len(length(rules)), lengths(rules))) 
  invisible(lapply(seq_len(length(rules_dt[[1]])), f))
})

# user  system elapsed 
# 3.27    0.43    3.70
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a little lo-fi, I'm sure there are much more fancy `dplyr` and `data.table` ways of doing this, but at least it's fairly transparent. The speed aspect you'll have to judge, but it's all vectorized, so should be fairly quick.

What I did was first build a few rules vectors. Does it start with an `A`, does it start with a `B`, does it start with a `C`, is the second character a `0`, how many characters are there, etc.
Then I use these vectors to build the group vectors by combining the rules vectors using logic operators.
Lastly the `group` vector was built from these taking advantage of the fact that e.g `TRUE*2 == 2` and `FALSE*3 == 0`. `0` will therefore be returned if the diagnosis fits with no group. If a diagnosis fits with more than one group it will get a bit confusing.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  ID = seq_len(10),
  diagnosis = c('A012', 'A02', 'B23', 'C43', 'B023', 
                'A99', 'A023', 'B012', 'B04', 'A07'),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE  

)

dat <- within(dat, {
    A=grepl("^A", diagnosis)
    B=grepl("^B", diagnosis)
    C=grepl("^C", diagnosis)
    z=grepl("^.0+", diagnosis)
    n=nchar(diagnosis)

    gr1=(A & n > 3)
    gr2=(B & z)
    gr3=(C & !z)

    group=(gr1 + gr2*2 + gr3*3)
  }
  )
```

Comment: I think I understand - so you're building the rules manually? That will definitely be a lot faster! There are no diagnoses in more than one group, fortunately. The only downside is that the 'rules' are quite long and are likely to change, and I think this approach means writing a couple of lines of code for each rule?

Comment: @DanLewer: Well, this solution assumes there to be a pattern in your rules, say every diagnosis starting with an `A` belongs in group `1`. If it's followed by a two-digit code, then it belongs to group `1.1`, if it's followed by a three-digit code then it belongs to group `1.2` etc. This is handy if new diagnoses are added, but the rules still hold. Say `B089` is comes up and it belongs in group `2.2`, then you don't have to change anything, because the rule still holds.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness I've also found a better solution using `grep`, which loops over the rules rather the rows. I've timed the solutions below. The `stringi` options is the best but the alternative `grep` approach is much better than my original solution:

```
# rules and dataset

rules <- list(
  group1 = c('A012', 'A02', 'C30'),
  group2 = c('B01', 'B02'),
  group3 = c('C01', 'D03')
)

D <- 100000
diagnoses <- c('A012', 'A02', 'C30', 'B01', 'B02', 'C01', 'D03', 'X99', 'X100', 'XA99', 'A99', 'D99')

dat <- data.frame(
  ID = seq_len(D),
  diagnosis = sample(diagnoses, D, replace = T),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

# initial approach

rules2 <- lapply(rules, paste, collapse = '|')

group <- function(y) {
  a <- sapply(rules2, grepl, x = y)
  a <- names(a)[a]
  return(if (length(a) == 0) NA else a)
}

ptm <- proc.time()
dat$group <- sapply(dat$diagnosis, group)
proc.time() - ptm

table(dat$group)

# alternative looping approach (across rules rather than cases)

dat$group <- NULL

ptm <- proc.time()

D <- sapply(rules2, grepl, dat$diagnosis)
dat$group <- ifelse(rowSums(D) == 0, NA, max.col(D))

proc.time() - ptm

table(dat2$group)

# stringi approach

dat$group <- NULL

library(stringi)
rules_dt <- list(rules = unlist(rules, use.names = FALSE), 
                 grp = rep(seq_len(length(rules)), lengths(rules)))

ptm <- proc.time()
lapply(1:length(rules_dt[[1]]), function(x) dat[stri_detect_fixed(dat$diagnosis, rules_dt$rules[x]), "group"] <<- rules_dt$grp[x])
proc.time() - ptm

table(dat$group)
```